# How can I install Emerald Theme Manager, and switch between Emerald and Metacity themes?

Tags: 11.10, themes, metacity, emerald

I want to get Emerald Theme Manager to work in Ubuntu 11.10 and activate its themes. Also, I want to be able to switch between Emerald themes and the originally installed (Metacity) themes. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution is to install `emerald` version 0.9.5 **via PPA** :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install emerald
```

After installation, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `emerald --replace`.
And if u want to get back to gtk themes press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gtk-window-decorator --replace`.

---

source: 
        [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-emerald-in-ubuntu-1110-oneiric.html)

Answer (score 3):

Since `emerald` is not in the Ubuntu repos in 11.10, this [thread has a workaround to install `emerald`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1870792). To use `emerald`, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then type `emerald --replace`. If you're going to stick with `emerald`, add the command to your startup applications. To go back to Metacity, type this: `gtk-window-decorator --replace`.

Comment: It is not in the repository by default, so it gave me (Unable to locate package emerald)

Comment: You're right check this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1870792